# Blinking cursor and black screen when trying to boot from USB

Tags: 12.04, live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I made Ubuntu 12.04 USB stick with unetbootin. When I select my USB drive in boot menu, I immediately get a black screen and blinking cursor. What causes this?

Comment: This sounds like a bad USB image, try checking the MD5 of the download before making the USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you make it with Linux Live USB Creator - http://www.linuxliveusb.com. If the problem still occurs try changing the flash drive.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I used Linux Live USB but still got the same problem.