# Blinking cursor trying to boot from live USB

Tags: boot, live-usb, eeepc

I have been trying to boot Lubuntu 16.04.1 on an Asus Eee PC 700 Series 2G Surf from a Live USB. I have tested the USB on two other computers, and Lubuntu starts smoothly, but I have been having some difficulty in getting it to boot on the Eee PC.

I have tried the various suggestions for ["My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it). Using `nomodeset` has no effect, and neither do `nolapic` nor `noapic` (nor any combination of these three). Setting `acpi = off` consistently causes it to become stuck trying to start Login Service, Light Display Manager, and Network Manager.

I have tried using `text` rather than `quiet splash`, but this does not seem to help me with figuring out what causes the problem.

The solution suggested in ["Blinking cursor and black screen when trying to boot from USB [duplicate]"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127578/blinking-cursor-and-black-screen-when-trying-to-boot-from-usb) also does not seem to be helpful, as I am certain that the Live USB *does* work, but not on this specific machine.

**Edit:** Trying out a fresh install of Lubuntu 16.04.1 from a live USB on the Eee PC works perfectly. I'm thinking that the failure with the original live USB either has something to do with a previous installation I had performed on the original live USB (e.g. a driver), or with changes I had made to fix [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1489855). Since I can boot from other computers, is there something I can do to figure out and fix what might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

For the others who read this...
My solution:

When creating the live USB using Rufus, two options are Presented ISO and DD.
Rufus recommends ISO, but after having the same issue I tried the DD option and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the blank screen, instead of the graphical Ubuntu live CD interface, you could try

```
* press `TAB` - for a prompt
* type "live"`ENTER`
```

This is what I sometimes had to do to get into the Live CD on my asus X54-C

Comment: Pressing tab at the blank screen appears to do nothing. Pressing tab at the interface ("Installer boot menu") allows me to edit the menu entries. I'm not sure where I press tab to get a prompt.